How to tell GCC that a pointer is non-null?
I'm trying to eliminate warnings from a block of code. It has this function:
 void OPN2_Reset(ym3438_t *chip, Bit32u rate, Bit32u clock)
 {
     Bit32u i, rateratio;
     rateratio = (Bit32u)chip->rateratio;
     memset(chip, 0, sizeof(ym3438_t));
     ...

This generates a build-time warning:
In function ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘void Ym2612_NukedImpl::OPN2_Reset(ym3438_t*, Bit32u, Bit32u)’ at /home/logiclrd/zdoom/zmusic_build/zmusic/thirdparty/game-music-emu/gme/Ym2612_Nuked.cpp:1413:11,
    inlined from ‘void Ym2612_Nuked_Emu::reset()’ at /home/logiclrd/zdoom/zmusic_build/zmusic/thirdparty/game-music-emu/gme/Ym2612_Nuked.cpp:1842:45:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59:33: warning: argument 1 null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull]
   59 |   return __builtin___memset_chk (__dest, __ch, __len,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   60 |                                  __glibc_objsize0 (__dest));
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59:33: note: in a call to built-in function ‘void* __builtin_memset(void*, int, long unsigned int)’

I've tried a whole bunch of searches to try to figure out how to tell the compiler that chip isn't NULL here, and I've tried various things and nothing seems to work.
// DOESN'T WORK
if (chip != NULL)
  memset(chip, 0, sizeof(ym3438_t));

// DOESN'T WORK
ym3438_t tmp;
ym3438_t *chip_nonnull = &tmp;
if (chip != NULL)
  chip_nonnull = chip;
memset(chip_nonnull, 0, sizeof(ym3438_t));

// DOESN'T WORK
assert(chip != NULL);
memset(chip, 0, sizeof(ym3438_t));

How do I make a call to memset only when chip is non-null, to avoid this warning? Or, how do I instruct the compiler to treat chip as non-null?

Can you show a [mre] that produces this warning?  Something any of us could compile to see the same warning.  The warning seems to imply that gcc knows that the value is null in file Ym2612_Nuked.cpp line 1413.

It seems that the compiler has done a static analysis that shows the pointer really is null.  You have to include the code that calls this function to see how that could be.

I'll have a go at minimal. In the meantime, it is trivially reproducible (just not minimal) by cloning github.com:/ZDoom/ZMusic and building it (mkdir build ; cd build ; cmake .. ; make).

One way is to switch to using a reference parameter instead of using a pointer.  That guarantees that you have a valid object to work on.  Then you just change the memset call to memset(&chip, 0, sizeof(ym3438_t));.

Unrelated to your problem, but any time you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion (the cast you do for the assignment to rateratio) you should take that as a sign that you're probably are doing something wrong.

@MarkRansom Why does it raise the warning even in the case of the second DOESN'T WORK? In that case, chip_nonnull can never be NULL. It is initialized to a non-NULL value, and then the value of chip is copied only if it is not NULL.

Also note that in C++, the symbols NULL is a C backward compatibility macro. Please use nullptr instead.

@Someprogrammerdude Fair enough :-) This is a third-party codebase and I'm just trying to eliminate warnings from the build, for no particular personal gain.

The warning that you see does not have false positives in the sense that there is no heuristic. If you see this, then there is somewhere a call to your function that the compiler was able to inline/constant-fold so that the pointer is null. The only thing that may be a false positive is that the particular call site may not actually be evaluated in the program execution (in this case these types of warnings are pretty annoying).

Okay, I see. In that case you could let it be for the time being, but I would take it as a warning that the third-party might be more comfortable with C than C++, and therefore there might be flaws in the C++ code.

chip sure looks NULL to me.  if ( !chip_r ) Ym2612_NukedImpl::OPN2_Reset( chip_r, ...

@DrewDormann Hey, nice catch! Looks like a straight-up bug. If I had to guess, the if condition is the wrong way around. I find it really weird that I still got the warning even with the second attempted work-around, but crossing fingers that flipping that if will make it go away.

@DrewDormann Yep, that did the trick. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

@DrewDormann nice job, I never would have assumed the source code was publicly available.

Thanks, @MarkRansom.  This site has taught me to google strange-looking filenames.

@JonathanGilbert "it is trivially reproducible (just not minimal) by cloning" -- Cloning is not trivial, and questions must be self-contained. Based on the error message, a minimal example should just need Ym2612_Nuked_Emu::reset() added. (The error message says that when Ym2612_Nuked_Emu::reset() calls Ym2612_NukedImpl::OPN2_Reset, the function was inlined, and when memset was called, that was also inlined.) Compile those two functions in isolation to confirm that is sufficient to reproduce the error, then experiment with removing lines.)

@JaMiT Okay :-) Well, I think ultimately it's a non-issue because the call site that triggered the warning in the first place was a blatant bug, as pointed out by DrewDormann. I've proposed the obvious fix to that as part of a PR upstream.

@JonathanGilbert "Well, I think ultimately it's a non-issue" -- And I think it's a critical issue for your question. As it stands, the question cannot be answered based on the information in the question. This makes the question basically useless in "a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming".

The pointer in question is null 100% of the time from the mentioned call stack.
That is why gcc is so confident in telling you argument 1 null where non-null expected
From the source:
if ( !chip_r ) Ym2612_NukedImpl::OPN2_Reset( chip_r, static_cast<Bit32u>(prev_sample_rate), static_cast<Bit32u>(prev_clock_rate) );
//   ^^^^^^^ if it's null...         pass it ^^^^^^


I'm confused as to why this still generates the warning:
//
ym3438_t tmp;
ym3438_t *chip_nonnull = &tmp; [definitely not NULL here]
if (chip) chip_nonnull = chip; [can't become NULL here]
memset(chip_nonnull, 0, sizeof(ym3438_t));
//
But this is definitely the actual cause, and almost certainly an actual bug. Thanks :-)

@JonathanGilbert The code in the question already has undefined behavior because of (Bit32u)chip->rateratio in the line before. If you do not remove that or make it use chip_nonnull as well, all bets are off.

That's a good point @user17732522, thanks :-)
